# Write an algorithm to efficiently find all i and j for any given N such that N=i^j

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an efficient algorithm of the problem, **for any N find all i and j such that N=i^j**.

I can solve it of **O(N^2)** as follows,

```
for i=1 to N
{
 for j=1 to N
 {
  if((Power(i,j)==N)
    print(i,j)
 }
}
```

I am looking for better algorithm(or program in any language)if possible.

Comment: whats wrong with this question.. why down vote ?

Comment: The language tag spam, even though your question is not related to any of the listed programming languages.

Comment: read the question carefully first... solution in the form of program segment in any of the mentioned language is also acceptable....

Comment: And yet you write in a pseudo-code syntax with a `for` loop that doesn't resemble any of C's, C++'s or Java's.

Comment: No, I am not begging the code i can write it myself if I get proper algorithm, but code segment is also acceptable.

Comment: One more reason behind choosing the tag is to highlight the question to more number of peoples.

Comment: There are tags like "language-agnostic" and "pseudocode" for a situation like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that `i^j=N`, you can solve the equation for `j` by taking the `log` of both sides:
 `j log(i) = log(N)` or `j = log(N) / log(i)`. So the algorithm becomes

```
for i=2 to N
{
    j = log(N) / log(i)
    if((Power(i,j)==N)
       print(i,j)
}
```

Note that due to rounding errors with floating point calculations, you might want to check `j-1` and `j+1` as well, but even so, this is an *O(n)* solution.

Also, you need to skip `i=1` since `log(1) = 0` and that would result in a divide-by-zero error. In other words, `N=1` needs to be treated as a special case. Or not allowed, since the solution for `N=1` is `i=1` and `j=any value`.

As M Oehm pointed out in the comments, an even better solution is to iterate over `j`, and compute `i` with `pow(n,1.0/j)`. That reduces the time complexity to *O(logN)*, since the maximum value for `j` is `log2(N)`.

Comment: Good solution. Wouldn't it be better to loop over `j` and calculate the `j`th root via `pow(n, 1.0 / j)`? The range of valid ´j`s is much smaller than the range of valid `i`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method you can use.

Lets say you have to solve an equation:

```
a^b = n         //b and n are known
```

You can find this using binary search. If, you get a condition such that,

```
x^b < n and (x+1)^b > n
```

Then, no pair (a,b) exists such that `a^b = n`.

If you apply this method in range for `b` from `1..log(n)`, you should get all possible pairs.

So, complexity of this method will be: O(log n * log n)

Follow these steps:

```
function ifPower(n,b)
    min=1, max=n;
    while(min<max)
        mid=min + (max-min)/2
        k = mid^b, l = (mid + 1)^b;
        if(k == n)
            return mid;
        if(l == n)
            return mid + 1;
        if(k < n && l > n)
            return -1;
        if(k < n)
            max = mid - 1;
        else
            min = mid + 2;       //2 as we are already checking for mid+1
    return -1;

function findAll(n)
    s = log2(n)
    for i in range 2 to s      //starting from 2 to ignore base cases, powers 0,1...you can handle them if required
        p = ifPower(n,i)
        if(b != -1)
            print(b,i)
```

Here, in the algorithm, `a^b` means `a raised to power of b` and not `a xor b` (its obvs, but just saying)

Comment: I was completing the answer as I thought it would be closed, so I posted it halfway. (To whoever downvoted this). I'm still completing the answer.